# Google Keep quick add item to list?

Tags: google-keep

Is there any "quick add entry to list" shortcut in Google Keep?

Previously I used a todo app on Android that let me have an icon on my homescreen for adding items to my list. One click and your're in the add entry input form.

Is there any similar widget/shortcut in Google Keep? I would like the least amount of clicks to add an item.

Comment: Yes, the Keep 4x1 and 4x4 widget has a button to add a quick note.

Comment: I don't really want to add a new note, I would like to add an entry to an existing list.

Comment: Lists? Keep just adds notes... It would be quicker to download it or use the http://keep.google.com to have a look how it works than for me to explain it tbh. You could just click on the note and add to it... if that works. I don't know what you want from it.

Comment: No, Google Keep can keep lists of items too :)
I've got an unsorted todo list and when I'm on the go I want to add entries to this list from my Android device with the least amount of clicks. Then when I'm back on my computer I sort this list.

Comment: Yep my bad. Am blind, it's buried in the UI a little. So there is only the option in the Widget to "Add a quick list" IF your list is on the widget you can click it and edit / add to it. But the Widget only displays about 3 or so objects in it (list or note) so unless it's up the top regularly that won't work out.

Comment: After a week of use I can say that my question really is a non issue. Keep launches very fast and remembers the list you left the app in last. All I have to do is to launch Keep and start typing, no extra clicks required and I'm happy :)

Comment: Cool, well that's handy! I've only really started using it myself to be honest so I'm not too familiar with it. Usually use calendar for personal stuff and Evernote for work stuff.